# TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn)) error in my code

Tags: ejs

My setup:

```
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"ejs": "^3.1.5",
"express": "^4.17.1"
```

My code:

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express=require("express");
const bodyparser=require("body-parser");

const app=express();
app.use("view engine","ejs");


app.get("/",function(req,res){
  var dati= new date();
  var day="";
  if(dati.getdate()>0 && dati.getdate()<6)
  {
    day="weekday";
    res.render("list.ejs",{ab: day});
  }
  res.send();

});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("server started at 3000");
});
```

I get the following error:

```
 throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
app.use("view engine","ejs");
```

Use:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

make sure you injection is right as well <%=     %>

[Express app.set, vs app.use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417772/express-app-set-vs-app-use)